# Toggling between Font Awesome styles on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm an aspiring web designer and need help with an issue I'm having. I have an icon in Font Awesome that I want to change colour/style when I hover on it.

Here is the default style I'd like to use:

CSS

```
.fa-circle {
  color:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94n0zxbt/2/

and here is what I'd like to have it change to on hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/94n0zxbt/5/

CSS

```
.fa-circle {
  color:white;
  border-color: red;
  border-radius: 90px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.fa-arrow-right {
  color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Thanks,

Ashley

Answer (score 1):

The reason the normal :hover css isn't working is that the `<i>` tags are overlapping each other. If you put the arrow `<i>` tag inside the circle `<i>` it will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjpwea/94n0zxbt/6/

You will notice that the arrow has gotten twice as big (I assume this is from the '2x' class), not super familiar with Font Awesome but there is probably an easy fix.